# Webstorm clear "recent files list" from the "Open File or Project" wizard

Tags: ide, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

In Webstorm version 9, when i open a project or file it remembers every file that i opened in the "Open File or Project" wizard.

I open the wizard by navigating to "File" ==> "Open", and then click the "Recent files" icon.

How do I clear this list?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following solution:

1. Open the following file:
   **/.Webstorm/config/options/options.xml**
2. On the XML property "**file.chooser.recent.files**" you can see a list of file path.
3. Edit the list as you wish
4. Note the text that separates between paths: `&#10;`